# On the HTML5 Video Player, how can I tell the type of the source being played?

Tags: html5-video

I'm providing DASH, HLS, and MP4 (as a fallback) as sources to an HTML5 Video player element. I would like to log the source types that my users end up using, but I don't know where to get that information from.

What's the best way for me to get this source type? I expected to be able to at least parse the video element's currentSrc property to figure this out, but there's nothing in the value that indicates whether it's dash/hls/mp4.

Comment: What does currentSrc return then?

Comment: Here's an example: blob:http://some.domain.com/77a91032-eecc-4417-a0f9-e44330637f13

...which isn't the location of any of the transcodes